# A normed space is Banach iff its unit sphere is complete

Tags: banach-spaces, normed-spaces, complete-spaces

Let $X$ be a non-trivial (other than singleton $x$) normed space. Prove that $X$ is a Banach space if and only if $\{x \in X \mid \|x\| = 1 \}$ is complete.

Comment: @OmkarDevelkar If you can show how you attempted to solve the problem. Also here is http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference for properly displaying numbers and functions.

Comment: Cauchy sequences are bounded, hence there exists $M$ such that $\frac{1}{M}x_n$ is a sequence in the closes unit ball, hence...

Comment: This would prove that close unit ball complete (and not unit circle) implies that X is Banach

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

Consider a Cauchy sequence $\{x_n\}$. See what happens with
$$\left\{\frac1{\|x_n\|}x_n\right\}$$

(Note that you also have to consider sequences with zeros).

Comment: ok i got it, thank you